# Package answers: is it possible to append all solutions to one output file?

Tags: answers

I am trying to use the package answers and found the answer to "[Please explain \Newassociation and provide an overview of how the package answers works](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22339/please-explain-newassociation-and-provide-an-overview-of-how-the-package-answer?rq=1)" very useful. However, when working with answers I ran into another problem. I am writing a book with chapters and at the end of each chapter I use the package answers to create problems and write solutions to a file. However, each chapter will have its own file with solutions and in the end of the book I have to input each of these in the correct order. So if I change the order of the chapters I have to change the order of the input commands. I would prefer to have all solutions in the same file, i.e. not use `\Opensolutionfile`, but instead an `\Appendsolutionfile`-command. Then I could just have one input-command in the solutions chapter. Is this possible?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to preserve the order in which the solutions appear, coinciding with the chapters?

Comment: Could you make a small example with a couple of chapters? If the solutions are to be input at the end of the document, there should be no problem in defining a final `\inputsolutions` macro that will input the solution files  the right order.

Answer (score 5):

This can be achieved by using chapter-specific solution files, here I used the name of the file, appended the chapter number, so each chapter writes to `foo1.tex`, `foo2.tex` etc. and afterwards, the command `\CollectAllSolutions` inputs all solution files in the order they have been written.

The writting is done automatically, by each chapter, in order to keep it simple for the user of such a feature (i.e. he/she does not have to specifiy the `\Opensolutionfile/\Closesolutionfile` each time a chapter starts. I have redefined the `chapter` start a little bit.

There are of course some things to make it more sophisticated, queries etc.

The 'example' exercises are taken and adapted from the `answers` documentation
by J. Wright.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{answers}
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{totcount}%
\Newassociation{sol}{Solution}{ans}
\newtheorem{ex}{Exercise}


\let\LaTeXStandardChapter\chapter
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\unstarredchapter@noopt}[1]{%
\unstarredchapter@opt{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\unstarredchapter@opt}[2][]{%
\LaTeXStandardChapter[#1]{#2}%
\Closesolutionfile{ans}
\Opensolutionfile{ans}[\jobname\number\value{chapter}]
}

\newcommand{\starredchapter}[1]{%
\LaTeXStandardChapter*[#1]%
}

\newcommand{\unstarredchapter}{%
\@ifnextchar[{\unstarredchapter@opt}{\unstarredchapter@noopt}
}%

\renewcommand{\chapter}{%
\@ifstar{\starredchapter}{\unstarredchapter}
}%
\makeatother

\newcounter{loopcounter}

\newcommand{\CollectAllSolutions}[1]{%
  \setcounter{loopcounter}{1}%
  \forloop{loopcounter}{1}{\number\value{loopcounter} < #1}{%
    \IfFileExists{\jobname\number\value{loopcounter}}{\input{\jobname\number\value{loopcounter}}}{}%
  }%

}%



\begin{document}

\newcounter{chaptercounter}%
\regtotcounter{chapter}%
\chapter{Problems}
\begin{ex}
First exercise
\begin{sol}
First solution.
\end{sol}
\end{ex}
\begin{ex}
Second exercise
\begin{sol}
Second solution.
\end{sol}
\end{ex}


\chapter{Problems 2}
\begin{ex}
Third exercise
\begin{sol}
Third solution.
\end{sol}
\end{ex}
\begin{ex}
Fourth exercise
\begin{sol}
Fourth solution.
\end{sol}
\end{ex}

\chapter{Solutions}

\CollectAllSolutions{\totvalue{chapter}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Why use separate answer files for each chapter? The outline that follows is not a complete compilable MWE, but does work in my book project.

In the preamble:

```
\usepackage{answers}
\newcommand{\answerFileName}{allanswers}

\Newassociation{sol}{Solution}{\answerFileName}

\renewenvironment{Solution}[1]
{
\vspace{0.15in}\hrule\vspace{0.15in}
{\textbf{Exercise #1}}
\par 
}
{}


% in a macro called at the start of each chapter:
\Writetofile{\answerFileName}{%
\noexpand\chapter{\mychaptername}%
}
}
```

In `main.tex`:

```
\input{preamble}
\Opensolutionfile{\answerFileName}

%% \include various chapters

\Closesolutionfile{\answerFileName}
```

Then you can `\include{\answerfilename}` in your main document or (as I do) include it in a separate document for solutions. My solution document looks like this:

[image]

**...**

[image]

generated from `chapter2.tex` code

```
\begin{exx} Drive carefully!

Suppose you drive from Here to There at a speed of 30 miles/hour
and then drive back from There to Here at 60 miles/hour. 

What is your average speed?

\begin{hint}
\emph{Warning}: it's not 45 miles/hour.

The problem does not say how far it is from Here to There. You're free
to pick some convenient distance to work with if you like.
\end{hint}

\begin{sol}
Imagine that the trip from Here to There is 60 miles. Then it takes two
hours to get there and one hour to come back. That's three hours for
the 120 mile round trip, so the average speed is (120~miles)/(3~hours
40~miles/hour.

This conclusion surprises many people. You can see the idea even more
clearly if you imagine that it's possible to make the return trip at
infinite speed -- in no time at all. Then the average speed is
(120~miles)/(2~hours) = 60~miles/hour, which is \emph{not} the average
of 30 and infinity. 

\end{sol}

\end{exx}
```

The `exx` environment manages Exercise numbering. The `hint`s appear at the end of the book, also done with the `answers` package.

Comment: This is also a good solution. I used another approach, which allows to omit some solutions (however, the code has still to be written) by specific chapters.