# book with theory exercises and separated answers

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I have a 300 page long book of mathematics, nine chapters, each chapter containing theory and exercises. I want to make another chapter at the end with all the answers. But if I add another question, which I frequently do, than the answers should be updated also.
Is there a package for things like that?

Comment: You might be interested to see that question [How to defer content to a later part of the document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/224408)

Comment: I couldn't find something like that, but thanks, maybe this will answer my question!

Comment: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/answers

Comment: there's some nice commentary on the `answers` package with this question: [Please explain \Newassociation and provide an overview of how the package answers works](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22339/579)